# Neutron star hit by asteroid

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, neutron-stars

Let’s say we have a very massive neutron star. It gets hit by a sizable asteroid. The combined object becomes massive enough for an event horizon to form. According to what we know, would the neutron star itself necessarily change all that much during these events?

Comment: What do you mean by "change all that much"? It's becoming a black hole, of course it's changing?

Comment: @Allure - I mean if the neutron star was extremely massive and only about 30 km across. For an event horizon to form it would only need to collapse to roughly a third of that radius. Why would it necessarily become a singularity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, of course it would change. Neutron stars and black holes are very different.

A neutron star is at equilibrium: the attractive force of gravity is balanced by the repelling [neutron degeneracy pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter#Neutron_degeneracy).

The formation of the event horizon is a point of no return. The matter inside the horizon is doomed to spaghettify onto a spacelike singularity or a ringularity (in case of nonzero angular momentum), until quantum gravity effects take over (at this point we don't know what will happen). This is an irreversible process, so far from equilibrium.

Comment: How do we know it is doomed to spaghettify though? Once the event horizon forms at the mass-radius ratio we get zero further information

Comment: @Wookie we use General Relativity to calculate its motion and the tidal forces.

Comment: Ok. So, what you’re saying is that by using GR we see that the amount of tidal force at any black hole event horizon will not permit remnants of a (former) neutron star to remain. All neutrons will be broken down. That’s clear. Thank you

Comment: This answer is incorrect in more than one part. First, there is no matter inside the horizon. The horizon expands from the ceter and pushes all matter out with a diverging force of the linear frame dragging. Secondly, there is no gravity inside the horizon, because the spatial gradient of the time diation is zero (whether or not you use the inner Schwarzschild metric). So no tidal forces or spaghettification either, even if matter hypothetically could be there.

Comment: @safesphere that's interesting. I will delete my answer since you say it is factually incorrect, but first, please provide references? Are you looking at a specific collapsing sphere solution?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov your answer is fine. Nothing in @safesphere’s objection is accurate. In both analytical solutions like Oppenheimer Snyder collapse and in more realistic numerical solutions of collapse there is matter inside the horizon during some periods and there is always arbitrarily strong tidal gravity near the singularity (by definition). His comment is false, there is no need to delete your answer

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov In a spherically symmetric star collapse, the horizon first forms in the center where the gravitational potential (time dilation) diverges. Learn what the linear frame dragging is to understand what happens to matter while the horizon expands from the center. And please never mind Dale's comments with no logic or math, but opinions based on popular misconceptions.

Comment: @safesphere please provide references to back up your claims, or at least write an answer outlining the logic and math you claim to be using.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov The horizon forms at the center, because the gravitational potential is extremal there: "*the event horizon ... first appears at the stellar center and moves monotonically outward in area*" - http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1980ApJ...235..199S&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf - Frame dragging means nothing at the horizon moves relative to it: "*Linear frame dragging is the similarly inevitable result of the general principle of relativity*" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging - Comments are not for discussions, please do your own research.

Comment: @safesphere there is no contradiction between that claim and what I have in my answer, and I don’t see why you would bring up frame dragging in this context. WRT your final point, comments are for clarification. It is not my fault that it took 3 comments to finally get you to provide a reference to your claim. “Do your own research” does not apply when I clearly disagree with your position. And there is no need to be rude — I have been nothing but respectful of your opinion in this thread.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov You clearly don't understand my explanations of why this answer is incorrect. So there is no point in continueing this conversation. I wasn't rude, just brief since moderators have threatened me for lengthy discussions in comments.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Please see the original Oppenheimer Snyder paper https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.56.455 which has been well-known for about 80 years by actual scientists. There is an analytical expression for the collapsing metric. From that you can directly compute all the curvature tensors and show that the Ricci curvature is non-zero inside the horizon, indicating the presence of matter, and that the Riemann curvature diverges at the singularity, indicating infinite tidal gravity. Your answer remains fine and the criticisms by safesphere are incorrect

Comment: @Dale you don’t have to convince me — I knew this already. Safesphere obviously has some other contradicting sources, I would like to see them, but the link they posted here doesn’t really contain much information on the topic.